# why do I need to update nfds in select call when I remove fds from master set?

Tags: c, sockets, select

Given a select call like this:

```
select(fdMax+1, &readFds, NULL, NULL, &timeoutVal)
```

where readFds are updated whenever

- new fd is added
- existing fd is removed

Whenever new fd is added, I update the `fdMax`. However, whenever existing fd is removed, I'm wondering `if I really need to update the fdMax also` ?

What difference does it make if I have a higher fdMax in there with not enough fds to read on ?

Comment: It's worth noting that you should almost always use either `poll` (which is POSIX) or something OS-specific like `epoll` or `kqueue`.

Comment: @o11c: The kernel implementation of `select` is fairly efficient. User code relying on `select` often maintain their own "sparse array" of active file descriptors which they compare against the returned set to avoid walking the set with `while (fd < fdMax) FD_ISSET(++fd, &readfds)`, and instead use `while (i < fdCount) FD_ISSET(fds[++i], &readfds)`.

Comment: @jxh I use `::` to demarcate this function is in the global namespace within my c++ code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just set `fdMax` to the maximum file descriptor value supported by your system (which may be represented by `FD_SETSIZE`), and not worry about it, but it may cause inefficiencies. `select` will use the `fdMax` value as a hint of when it can stop its linear scan of the file descriptor table. If you lie to `select`, it will likely cause it to loop for much longer than is actually needed to find the file descriptors of interest.

In Linux, the function `max_select_fd` uses the `fdMax` to start a backward scan for the relevant file descriptors.<sup>[LXR](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/select.c#L342)</sup>

In FreeBSD, the function `kern_select` will adjust `fdMax` to the highest open file descriptor for the process if `fdMax` is larger.<sup>[FXR](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/kern/sys_generic.c?v=FREEBSD10#L971)</sup> For a pure server, this looks to be a good heuristic choice, but may still be too large for a system that is careful to keep socket file descriptors at lower values than other file descriptors.

Comment: `FD_SETSIZE` is the size of the bit array in `fd_set`.

Comment: @o11c: Thanks, I have adjusted the answer. This is sometimes just a constant that is fed to some array declaration, and on such a system, it is "possible" to increase the number of file descriptors `select` can handle by redefining `FD_SETSIZE` to a larger value.

Comment: Yeah, I've done that (also arguably you should always `setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE)` to the current TU's `FD_SETSIZE`). But regardless of whether or not you've redefined it, in any given TU it will match the size of your `fd_set`. Of course, having different TUs with different definitions is just asking for trouble, it really belongs in `CPPFLAGS`.

Answer (score -1):

there is a pre-defined symbol (maxfd) that you can use.  Then never have to modify that parameter regardless of the number of actual FDs being used.

Comment: I have never heard of this and it's certainly not in my libc.